# Cooking soup pattern

Tags: design-patterns

So I came up with a pattern and since patterns, by definition, are something everyone comes up with over and over again, I have a feeling this one must already have a name. It's just that I'm not sure how to google it and never read about it on the web in the past. So ... can anyone recognise this and put a name to it?

I call it cooking soup. It's a class that essentially has two methods:

- add(something1, something2, ...)
- cook()

add() is like throwing ingredients into the pot, and cook() is like asking for a final result. I use it to dynamically build a structure (an object tree) and fill it with data. For example, when building an object hierarchy from an SQL `ResultSet`, I just feed the row data into the soup and then cook() it to get a collection of some objects that were built using that data.

In my actual implementation I use two different add() methods, as sometimes not all ingredients are available, though result is largely the same.

I use the same soup implementation to build another object tree using different data source, like from JSON.

So I guess you could look at this thing from the other side and call it "An object hierarchy builder with an interchangeable data source".

It's not a `Builder`, because builders usually have clearly-defined methods that add specific pieces to the process. Using a builder usually means understanding the underlying structure. But here I'm just throwing lots of stuff at it without having to know anything about the thing I'm actually making.

Comment: It is not a pattern, at least one which is common place and I am sure it doesn't have a known name..maybe you can do `Cook(somethig)`

Comment: Do you use `add(resultSet)` or do you pick out the individual attributes and add them individually?  eg `add(col1, col2, col3, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr: Based on your description above, if you call `add` once it's a one-off Factory.  If you call `add` more than once then it's a confused Builder.  Either way, you're probably better off with the tried-and-true rather than your `Soup`.

Let me start by restating what I (think I) understand about your potentially new pattern.  You have an object, `Soup`, that you create.  You then `add` in a list of "ingredients" (arguments).  Finally, you `cook` the soup and it gives you back a new instance of some object based on the arguments you `add`ed.

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, and please correct me if I've misrepresented this, but from the above I think that this is actually an anti-pattern.  There are two patterns that it is very similar to, and it seems like it combines the worst of both of them.

The first is a Factory, or even a basic constructor.  I just don't see any value being added by a call to `add(...)` that couldn't be achieved by `new Whatever(...)` or `WhateverFactory.getNewWhatever(...)`.

The second pattern that it is very close to, which you've acknowledged in the question, is the Builder pattern.  You seem to be aware of the similarities so I won't harp on them.  I do want to mention the motivation behind the Builder pattern, however, and its drawbacks.  This pattern was created so that objects can present a cleaner creation interface to their consumers.  Wikipedia refers to it as the [telescoping constructor anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), where the class's constructor list becomes incoherently long.  The benefit is that you get a cleaner interface.  One of the drawbacks is that you have to store the state of your object before you actually create it, which in thread-safe contexts means that for every object you want, you end up creating at least 2: one builder and one desired object.  Another often-overlooked drawback is that it breaks the expectation of your users- they want to `new Whatever`, because that's how everything else in the language works.  You've broken that pattern, and depending on how good your documentation is (and how much your users care about reading it) they might have to spend some valuable time figuring that fact out.

The reason I mention these is that it seems like your `Soup` suffers from both of these drawbacks.  You need a new pot of `Soup` every time you want to create a new object, and it adds another layer of abstraction to get an object.  At the same time, it doesn't seem to simplify the interface to get a new object; you still have to pass in the exact same argument list you normally would to a constructor, or a Factory.

I was going to try to make a pun but I can't think of one.  So I'll just say that you should probably stop doing this.

If you disagree with what I've said above, please comment about any misconceptions about the usage or overlooked value it provides and I'll be happy to get back to you.